# Python download file from URL

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

Trying to download a file from this URL. It is an excel file and it downloads only 1 kb of it. While the file size is actually 7mb. I dont understand what has to be done here

But if copy and paste the url in IE, the entire file is downloaded

```
res = requests.get('http://fescodoc.***.com/fescodoc/component/getcontent?objectId=09016fe98f2b59bb&current=true')
res.raise_for_status()
playFile = open('DC_Estimation Form.xlsm', 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(1024):
    playFile.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `stream` to true in the `get()`,

```
res = requests.get('http://fescodoc.***.com/fescodoc/component/getcontent?objectId=09016fe98f2b59bb&current=true', stream=True)
res.raise_for_status()
with open('DC_Estimation Form.xlsm', 'wb') as playFile:
    for chunk in res.iter_content(1024):
        playFile.write(chunk)
```

See here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use built-in module `urllib` for such cases: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

```
urllib.urlretrieve('http://fescodoc/component/.', 'DC_Estimation_Form.xslm')
```

Comment: Still downloads only 1kb file.

Comment: Maybe the site sets incorrect Content-Length to fool scraping tools? I'd try using `curl -i http://fescodoc.. | less` to inspect headers returned by the site first. Also, try setting innocuously-looking `User-Agent` field, matching, for example, your browser user agent string.